# Form Validation Set Custom Validity

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I'm playing around with form validations.
I've build a simple captcha field and I want to check it via javascript.

At this point it works static. I need to add an eventlistener, but don't know how.

Hope, you can help.

HTML

```
<form>
  <input type="text" id="field_robot" name="">
  <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

JS

```
var val = document.getElementById('field_robot').value;
var field = document.getElementById('field_robot');

field.addEventListener('input', function(){
  if (val != '42') {
    field.setCustomValidity('invalid');
  } 
});
```

Comment: What exactly is your issue?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want the input field validated. Everytime the input of the "field_robot"-field is changed, it should be checked, if the input is 42.

Comment: You can add a onInput attribute to the input field. And add the function with the validation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is you're declaring `val` outside of your event listener. So, your value is never refreshed after the input. You need to retrieve the field's value inside the event listener.

See the snippet below :

```js
var field = document.getElementById('field_robot');

field.addEventListener('input', function() {
  var val = document.getElementById('field_robot').value;
  if (val != '42') {
    field.setCustomValidity('invalid');
  } else {
    event.target.setCustomValidity('');
  }
});
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" id="field_robot" name="">
  <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Now, you can go a bit further and have a listener you could use for several input fields, using the `event` object provided by the listener and a `fieldValidator` function that would take your event and a boolean condition as parameters.

See this other snippet :

```js
var field = document.getElementById('field_robot');

field.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
    fieldValidator(event, (field.value == '42'));
});

function fieldValidator(event, condition) {
    var val = event.target.value;
    if (!condition) {
        event.target.setCustomValidity('invalid');
    } else {
        event.target.setCustomValidity('');
    }

}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
      <input type="text" id="field_robot" name="">
      <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: `Input` is a standard event - https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#event-input-input

Comment: @catalin you're right. I updated. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: One extra thing. You can also do the form validation for all the elements, on the submit button click event. This way you centralize the validation into one place.

Comment: While you are correct, the OP asked for a validation happening upon changing the content of the input, not when submitting the form : "Everytime the input of the "field_robot"-field is changed, it should be checked, if the input is 42.".

Answer (score 0):

So now it works well.

```
  var field = document.getElementById('field_robot');

  field.addEventListener('change', function() {
  var val = document.getElementById('field_robot').value;
  if (val != '42') {
    field.setCustomValidity('invalid');
  } else {
    field.setCustomValidity('');
  };
});
```